Vite causing CORS error while sending object data of React app to Google Sheets
I am trying to use Google Sheets for storing my data of my React app. The following is my component code:

    const data = {
      ...userData,
      ...selectedOptions.reduce((acc, option, index) => {
        const alphabetOption = numericToAlphabets[option];
        acc[`question${index + 1}`] = alphabetOption;
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    };

    try {
      await axios.post(googleScriptUrl, data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

I am using the following AppScript for my project. I have named the columns in the sequence of my data field. The following is the Google Sheet AppScript
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("google-sheet-url").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const data = e.parameter;
  sheet.appendRow([
    data.name,
    data.email,
    data.education,
    data.gender,
    data.dateOfBirth,
    ...Object.keys(data).filter(key => key.startsWith("question")).map(key => data[key]),
  ]);

  // Set CORS headers
  const responseHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Allow requests from any origin (replace with specific origin if needed)
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
  };

  const response = ContentService.createTextOutput("Your message was successfully sent to the Google Sheet database!");
  response.setMimeType('application/json');
  response.setHeaders(responseHeaders);
  return response;
}


The following is the error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "google-sheet-url" (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Object { stack: "AxiosError@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=481c8f0f:377:18\nhandleError@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=481c8f0f:1450:14\n", message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }```

How can I debug this error?


Hello Rajveer !! Welcome to stackoverflow.
Here might be the answer you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546969/cors-authorization-on-google-sheets-api-requests.

I was not able to figure out how to debug the error. Can you please help me out!

Can you provide your whole script of Google Apps Script? And, can you provide the sample value of data? If you are using Web Apps of Google Apps Script, can you provide the detailed setting of your Web Apps?

I used fetch along with a proxy server instead of using get and post, and now it works fine for me. Here's the code:
    const proxyUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
const targetUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_GoogleAppScript;
console.log(data);

try {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(data);
  const body = params.toString();

  const response = await fetch(`${proxyUrl}${targetUrl}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: body,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  });

Here's the Google App Script:
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("google-sheet-url");
const sheet = sheets.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doPost(e) {
  const data = e.parameter;

  console.log("Received Data:", data);

  const name = data.name;
  const email = data.email;
  const education = data.education;
  const gender = data.gender;
  const dateOfBirth = data.dateOfBirth;
  const question1 = data.question1;
  const question2 = data.question2;
  const question3 = data.question3;
  const question4 = data.question4;
  const question5 = data.question5;
  const question6 = data.question6;
  const question7 = data.question7;
  const question8 = data.question8;
  const question9 = data.question9;
  const question10 = data.question10;


  sheet.appendRow([name, email, education, gender, dateOfBirth, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10]);

    const response = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data));
  response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  response.setStatusCode(200);
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"
  };
  return response.setResponseHeaders(headers);
}

And here's the proxyServer code:
import cors_anywhere from "cors-anywhere";

const host = "localhost";
const port = 8080;

cors_anywhere
  .createServer({
    originWhitelist: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    requireHeader: ["origin", "x-requested-with"],
    removeHeaders: ["cookie", "cookie2"],
  })
  .listen(port, host, function () {
    console.log(`Running CORS Anywhere on ${host}:${port}`);
  });

